# How do I determine $A^{50}$, given the eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that the eigenvalues of $A^{50}$ will just be the eigenvalues of $A$ raised to the $50$th power. I also tried working backwards from this conclusion, but I am unable to obtain the characteristic polynomial for $A^{50}$.

My eigenvectors here are (1, 1) and (2, 3).

What is the key insight to progressing with this question?

Comment: How does your matrix look like? How many eigenvectors do you have? I would add that to the question to get better answers.

Comment: Definitely @Shashi. Are you familiar with diagonalizing a matrix?

Comment: My matrix has eigenvectors of (1, 1) and (2, 3). I am familiar with diagonalizing, but I do not see how that is of help here. The original matrix is (4 -2
     
                3 -1) and is 2x2

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that (high) powers of matrices are, in general, annoying to compute. Powers of diagonal matrices however, are very easy: each diagonal element is simply raised to this power.

Now if you can diagonalize your matrix $A$ as $PDP^{-1}$, with $D$ diagonal and the invertible matrix $P$ containing the corresponding eigenvectors in the columns, then:
$$\begin{align}A^n
 & = \left( PDP^{-1} \right)^n \\
 & = PD\underbrace{P^{-1}P}_{I}D\underbrace{P^{-1}P}_{I}DP^{-1} \ldots PDP^{-1} \\
 & = PD^nP^{-1}
\end{align}$$
For $A^{50}$, you simply compute $D^{50}$ and perform the two extra matrix multiplications with $P$ and $P^{-1}$.

---

In your case with
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -2 \\ 3 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
you found eigenvectors $v_1 = (1,1)$ and $v_2 = (2,3)$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1=2$ and $\lambda_2=1$; so you get $P$ and $D$ as follows:
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \quad , \quad
D = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Find $P^{-1}$ and use the 'trick' from above.

Comment: What am I using here for the diagonal matrix, D? Is that just the diagonal with the eigenvalues?

Comment: The diagonal matrix $D$ contains the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, in the same order you place the corresponding eigenvectors in the matrix $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $TAT^{-1} = B$ be diagonal. Then $B^{50} = (TAT^{-1})^{50} = TA^{50}T^{-1}$, so 
$A^{50} = T^{-1}B^{50}T$, and powers of a diagonal matrix are easy to calculate.

Comment: Please use proper formatting !

Comment: Where do I find out how to do that?

Comment: Check here - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference